# The word Array is displayed as the first item

Tags: php, arrays

I am getting the values from an array this is taken from `jQuery.serialize()` just an input field. I then send then form data to a sendMail page.
Display the results in an email and the word `Array` is the first word then the value inputted follows, the rest of the data displayed is ok. 
I have four `arrays` and in front of each the word Array appears.

```
$qty = $_POST['qty'];
foreach($qty as $value)
{
 $qty .= $value . "<br>";
}

$desc = $_POST['description'];
foreach($desc as $value)
{
 $desc .= $value . "<br>";
}

$options = $_POST['options'];
foreach($options as $value)
{
 $options .= $value . "<br>";
}

$price = $_POST['price'];
foreach($price as $value)
{
 $price .= $value . "<br>";
}
```

input would be qty: 1, Desc: description, options: small, price: 1.99
output is Array 1, Array description, Array options, Array small.

only on the first line the rest of the lines are ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are concatenating  to the POST array you should do this instead:

```
$qty = $_POST['qty'];
foreach($qty as $value)
{
 $qty2 .= $value . "<br>";
}

echo $qty2;
```

Comment: That only displays one item and there are many items to be displayed

Comment: Sorry should be $qty2 = $value . "<br>";

Comment: This has helped me get the solution to work. I still need the `.=` operator as there are many items.

Answer (score 1):

Each part of your code contain the inconsistency of both assuming you have an array as POST-data and then assigning it as an string.

```
$possible_array = $_POST['possible_array'];
foreach($possible_array as $value)
{
   $possible_array .= $value . "<br>"; // < - here you use $possible_array as a string
}
```

One way forward should be to assign the string value to another string:

```
$possible_array = $_POST['possible_array'];
foreach($possible_array as $value)
{
   $string .= $value . "<br>"; // < - change to a new string
}
```

However it seem not probable that you actually have POST-data in arrays here I guess you send different items which each have the properties qty, description etc

I think you would like to use a solution where you iterate (foreach) on product info as an two-dimensional array, like `$_POST['products']['qty']` where `products` is an array. But to help you further you would need to include your POST-data to see how its structured/serialized.

Comment: How would I get round this? or change my code as the inputs are appened to a table and then `posted`

Comment: That seems a good idea. I might try that. I have made it not display by changing the assignment variable to $qtyOut and it displays ok. but this seems a good idea as I need to think about formatting my email correctly.

Answer (score 0):

That happens because you append the value of each array to the array itself. Due to the value being a string the result also becomes a string. So the array will implicitly be casted to a string which results in the word "Array".

Possible solution:

```
$qtyList = implode('<br>' , $_POST['qty']);
```